# Is there an experience table for Evoland?

Tags: evoland

Is there a listing of the experience points required to get to each level? And perhaps what each level gives(defense, attack, magic, etc.) per character?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know exactly but,i think there is not a table of experience, you always level up with **100xp.**
It takes more time to level up cause depending on your level, you get less experience points per monster killed. I don't know the calculations.

About what each level gives, the possibilites are:

1. +5 max heath.
2. +1 attack (or +1 magic for Kaeris).
3. +1 defense.

The order of this is different for Clink and Kaeris but they both loop every 3 levels.

Curiosity: No one ever found a level cap **yet**, since the game could be finished with level 8.